# Is a point inside a polygon? Problem with method

Tags: python, geometry, pose-estimation

First post in stackoverflow. Im working with TfPoseEstimator in python and need to know if a point of the human body is inside an area that I delimited in a polygon.
My problem is that the try block says: "Not working" for each part of the body.
Could someone help me?

```
def punto_en_poligono(x, y, poligono):
    i = 0
    j = len(poligono) - 1
    salida = False
    for i in range(len(poligono)):
        if (poligono[i][1] < y and poligono[j][1] >= y) or (poligono[j][1] < y and poligono[i][1] >= y):
            if poligono[i][0] + (y - poligono[i][1]) / (poligono[j][1] - poligono[i][1]) * (poligono[j][0] - poligono[i][0]) < x:
                salida = not salida
        j = i
    return salida 


humans1 = e.inference(recto, resize_to_default=(w > 0 and h > 0), upsample_size=args.resize_out_ratio)
poly1 = geometry.Polygon([[450,350],[478,0],[638,0],[638,350],[450,350]])

for j in humans1:
    for i in j.body_parts:
        try:
             pos_X = int(j.body_parts[i].x*960)                         
             pos_Y = int(j.body_parts[i].y*640) 
             is_Inside = punto_en_poligono(pos_X,pos_Y,poly1)
        except:
             print("Not working")
```

Expected True or False.
Actual results: "Not working"

Comment: you have a function in shapely which gives the result? do you know ?

Comment: If your expectation is for the program to work, I wouldn't recommend using an raw except , or even except. Running your code and looking at the error can be so much better ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution using shapely:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon

point0 = Point(500, 200)
point1 = Point(500, 0) 
poly1 = Polygon([[450,350],[478,0],[638,0],[638,350],[450,350]])

print(poly1.contains(point0)) #True
print(poly1.contains(point1)) #False
```

in your program you just replace the line: and you could delete the function `punto_en_poligono`

```
is_Inside = poly1.contains(Point(pos_X,pos_Y)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Im new in python and didnt know that. :D

Comment: that simplifies your program..!! if it helps dont forget to upvote/validate the answer